# Add blank row at the end of DataGridView to add values c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working with **DataGridView** in a form, and I am getting an error.
This is my DataGridView:

[image]

As you can see, there is a row to add values, and I add the following four rows:

- (DB)335T1613 0.5
- (DB)335T1642 3.87
- (DB)001122   0.9
- (DB)335T1644 3.71

And my DataGridView is ok:

[image]

But if I copy these data again I have 2 blank rows ...

[image]

So the problem is, how can I avoid this?

This is my code, and of course, I have to get the property **AllowUserAddRows** in true:

```
private void PasteClipboard()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Inicio de PasteClipboard.");

        try
        {
            string s = Clipboard.GetText();
            string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
            int iFail = 0, iRow = dataGridViewTennetPaint.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int iCol = dataGridViewTennetPaint.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            DataGridViewCell oCell;
            dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows.Add(lines.Length); //before was lines.Lenght - 1
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] sCells = line.Split('\t');
                for (int i = 0; i < sCells.GetLength(0); ++i)
                {
                    if (iCol + i < this.dataGridViewTennetPaint.ColumnCount)
                    {
                        oCell = dataGridViewTennetPaint[iCol + i, iRow];

                        if (!oCell.ReadOnly)
                        {
                            if (oCell.Value == null || oCell.Value.ToString() != sCells[i])
                            {
                                oCell.Value = Convert.ChangeType(sCells[i],
                                                      oCell.ValueType);
                            }
                            else
                                iFail++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    { break; }
                }
                iRow++;
                if (iFail > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} updates failed due" +
                                    " to read only column setting", iFail));
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The data you pasted is in the wrong format for the cell");
            return;
        }
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        row.CreateCells(dataGridViewTennetPaint);
        row.Cells[0].Value = "";
        row.Cells[1].Value = "";
        row.Cells[2].Value = "";
        dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows.Add(row); 
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fin PasteClipboard.");
    }
```

Comment: what is dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows.Add(row);  for?

Comment: @JuryGolubev to add an empty row at the end of the DataGridView

Comment: Well I understand what the function is for. 
But if you need to allow user edits you should not need to add any blank rows yourself - AllowUserAddRows for the datagrid and AllowNew for the datasource (if any) should do the trick

Comment: @JuryGolubev where can I find AllowNew? (I am new with this)

Comment: And if you intentionally add empty row, then I don't get what the problem is. You have your row with null values and a system row for entering data.

Comment: @JuryGolubev because if I dont add intentionally an empty row, there is not any row to add data.

Answer (score 1):

In case your clipboard string only holds your cell values + `'\n'` & `'\t'`:

Check for empty rows in your `foreach` statement, cut out `'\n'` and `'\t'` and check if the string is empty.

Comment: because maybe am I adding some empty rows?

Answer (score 0):

To have the ability to add new rows to datagridview 
you need to bind it to a datasource that will keep the data.

Try smth like below:

```
public class SomeClass{
public string Codigo {get;set;}
public string Superficie {get;set;}
public string Error {get;set;}
}

.....

var srcList = new List<SomeClass>();

.....

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = srcList;
bs.AllowNew = true;
bs.AddingNew += new AddingNewEventHandler(BindingSource_AddingNew); //(you may or may not need it depending on the collection used as bs.DataSource.

dataGridViewTennetPaint.AllowUserAddRows = true;
dataGridViewTennetPaint.DataSource = bs;
dataGridViewTennetPaint.DataBind();
```

This is meta-code. But should give you an idea.